# Need to work out an excel formula to get a starting and end time from some data I have

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to pull the start and end times for the data I have but I am unable to work out the formula.

The the current data shows blanks for when no sales occurred so the output would need to be something like 0800 - 2300 or if its in two columns it is fine.

Not sure this is even possible to be honest but would save more time to auto calculate as I have 50 shops to do.

Thanks you

[image: Example 1]

Comment: you say `the output would need to be something like 0800-2300` . What exactly is the condition to get 0800?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit for new file structure*

If the time is continuous, the following array formulas may be used:

for opening time-

```
{=LEFT(INDEX($B$1:$Y2,1,MATCH(--(B2<>""),--(B2:Y2=""),0)+COUNTIF(B2:Y2,"")*(B2<>"")),4)}
```

for closing time-

```
{=RIGHT(INDEX($B$1:$Y2,1,MAX(--(B2:Y2<>"")*(COLUMN(B2:Y2)-COLUMN(B2)+1)*(B2="")+((B2:Y2="")*(COLUMN(B2:Y2)-COLUMN(B2)+1)*(B2<>"")-COUNTIF(B2:Y2,"")*(B2<>"")))),4)}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have put the code on to my dummy excel and it doesn't seem to be pulling back any values for some reason.

Comment: @Coderlife hm, no error, just blank cell? Can you share your excel file?

Comment: How do I share the excel?

Comment: Put it in a file sharing service (eg OneDrive) and add a link to the your question.

Comment: I downloaded the one that was done on the shared folder but as soon as I downloaded the file and pressed enter on the formula it said Error in Value. Do you know why this is happening, its not working on my desktop either.

Comment: @Coderlife I edit formulas according new file structure. I edit sample workbook in OneDrive too (I don't know if you can see my changes). Note that these are array formulas. If your Excel version does not support dynamic arrays you must press CSE to confirm formula.

Comment: Thank you so much @basic, this has helped me save hours of my day going through store hours. You and The Gridlock are Absolute legends.